# Query scope in different table using Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I am using scope query in my Group list display, and Group belongs to Country table. I can use group name as search and sort order without any problem.

Want I want to do now are the following:

1) search country name which is stored in Country table

2) sort order country name which is stored in Country table

```
# Group Model #
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'group';
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function country() 
    {    
        return $this->belongsTo('country');
    }

    public function scopeName($query, $name)
    {
        return $query->where('group_name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
    }

    public function scopeSortName($query, $order_by = 'asc')
    {
         return $query->orderBy('group_name', $order_by);
    }
}

# Country Model #
class Country extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'country';

    public function groups() {
        return $this->hasMany('group');

    }
}

# Group Controller #
public function index()
{
    // search group name
    $groups = Group::name($s_name);

    // order group name
    $groups = $groups->sortName($orderBy);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way that I can sort the record using other column's table without joining it. Therefore in my controller I used JOIN query.

```
# Group Controller #
public function index()
{
    // join the table Group and Country tables
    $groups = Group::join('country', 'country.id', '=', 'group.country_id');

    // search group name
    $groups = $groups->name($s_name);

    // order group name
    $groups = $groups->sortName($orderBy);

}
```